# Can I have a discussion over a problem not posted on Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have written up a small idea which I would like to post on Vixra (or some other site just so I can make it official I came up with it) but I am interested in having some discussion over what I have done.

Would I be allowed to post a question that goes along the lines of:

"What are the difficulties of algorithm demonstrated in [link goes here]?". I would like some input about mistakes, problems, corrections"

I can assure you it will be very productive, especially to me, if I can get some input on the topic. I have no problem with posting the idea on SE itself but I feel it will be a little long and I've noticed a general trend that Long questions don't get looked at.

On a side note, is there a reason that longer written questions appear to receive less work than shorter ones?

Comment: It's likely that a lot of people here would instantly vote to close things related to viXra. But in any case, the answer is no. You can't ask people to read something just to answer your question. Make your question self contained and you might get an answer.

Comment: (And don't use viXra.)

Comment: I'm an undergrad... Arxiv is out of the question. Ill just have to convince ppl to take a look at it before they dismiss it based on the container

Comment: Why is there a downvote on this? Do please explain yourself as I am very curious.

Comment: On meta, downvotes usually express a negative response to the question you ask. In this case, the downvotes (among which is mine) express "In my opinion, you can't" as a response to the question in the title.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 7):

As Asaf says, questions on this site should be self-contained. But there is a more fundamental reason why your question would be off-topic. You state

> I would like some input about mistakes, problems, corrections

These kinds of questions can be very interesting, but they are not what math.SE is for. To quote from the Help Center:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

and

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about **__**”, then you should not be asking here.

To answer your other question (why longer questions receive less work than shorter ones): They require more effort to read and answer, so many users simply don't bother.

Comment: But I may have made a mistake. Since I am not 100% sure of the accuracy of my results but if they are innacurate it's beyond me to find why. Where can I go to have it discussed? I would like to make productive use of my work... Even if it means learning my mistake? Is there a site you can recommend at least?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas You might have more luck on the usenet group sci.math. But the issue is that what your asking for is a lot of relatively thankless work.

Comment: I would be understating in saying I am grateful. I don't really have too many avenues around this time of year

Comment: On a side note is there a more respectable archive site than Vixra? I understand now that there is a host of unprofessional literature on it... Which I would rather not associate with (though if it is the only option I do not mind

Comment: @frogeyedpeas It might be possible to post it on the arXiv. You just need to contact an endorser for the relevant subject area and convince them of the nonzero value of your work.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: in fact, ideally you should send your paper to a professor whom you know and who would be sympathetic and who will then (a) read it and point out any possible errors and (b) endorse you for submission to `arXiv`. (But make sure that said professor is an [arXiv endorser](http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) first!) This will kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: @WillieWong Of course, that is only possible if you know a math professor.

Comment: @AlexBecker I see I made the mistake assuming that [undergrads have generally met professors](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10076/can-i-have-a-discussion-over-a-problem-not-posted-on-math-se/10077?noredirect=1#comment37067_10076) `:-)`

Comment: @WillieWong Whoops, missed that :)